# Count amount of parameters sent to batch file

Tags: batch-file

How can I count the amount of command-line parameters sent to a batch file inside it. eg. from CMD I call `test.bat a b c d` would result `4` while `test.bat a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o` would result `15`. My current solution is:

```
@echo off
set var=0
if not "%~1"=="" set var=var+1
if not "%~2"=="" set var=var+1
if not "%~3"=="" set var=var+1
if not "%~4"=="" set var=var+1
if not "%~5"=="" set var=var+1
if not "%~6"=="" set var=var+1
if not "%~7"=="" set var=var+1
if not "%~8"=="" set var=var+1
if not "%~9"=="" set var=var+1
echo %var%
pause
```

This is a inefficient solution though, as a maximum of 9 can be detected

What would be an alternative?

Comment: But for a foolproof version read [Dostips: foolproof counting of arguments](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=2836)

Comment: See the `shift` command, its purpose is to handle any number of arguments.